# Restoring a mysql database in windows 10

Tags: mysql

[image]I am trying to restore a mysql database in windows 10 using the command below.

mysql -u root mydatabase < mydatabase.

My computer is quite fast but this is using about 99% of my disk space when I looked through my task manager. Sometime it takes about 2 hours to restore a database.

What can I do to make this faster?

Comment: (comment from SO) If binary logging is enabled, then you can disable binary logging for the session by including `--init-command="SET sql_log_bin=OFF;"` option on the mysql command. (I don't think it's "disk space", more likely you are looking at the disk utilization metric under Task Manager performance.) I/O is frequently the bottleneck with spinning platters. You'd get much higher throughput with SSD in place of HDD. Also make sure the mysqldump file is using multi-insert, not singleton insert statements.

Answer (score 2):

Mysqldump is single threaded so you’re bound by the speed that 1 core can run at to play all your SQL commands in serialised fashion. There are some config variables that can be changed to reduce the amount of disk flushes needed and permit larger memory buffers for speed.

Innodb (if that’s what engine you use) variables (plus others)

- innodb_buffer_pool_size
- Innodb_log_file_size
- innodb_flush_log_at_transaction_commit
- Sync_binlog

Should get your research and tuning off to a start to make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

That's not *space*, that's *speed*.  Note that the units is "MB/s", "MegaBytes *per second*".  The I/O is going full tilt, meaning that it is not possible to do the load any faster.  Multithreading, if possible, would *not* help.